# How to set default value of inputselect in lightning?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, picklist, lightning-design-system, code

I have tried several methods already but this still wont work. It defaults to the first option in the list.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_select.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputSelect.htm

currently, here's what I have

```
<ui:inputSelect class="slds-input slds-text-align-center" value="{! taskRec.status}">
    <aura:iteration items="{! v.status }" var="status" >
    <ui:inputSelectOption text="{! status }"/>
    </aura:iteration>
</ui:inputSelect>
```

taskRec.status - is being iterated as well. i displayed this in plain text and it returns the proper value
I just really need to set the same in the select option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ui_inputSelectOption.htm) of the ui:inputSelectOption:

> value : Boolean   Indicates whether the status of the option is selected.
>   Default value is “false”.

Then, you can use:

```
<ui:inputSelect class="slds-input slds-text-align-center">
    <aura:iteration items="{! v.status }" var="status" >
    <ui:inputSelectOption text="{! status }" value="{!status == taskRec.status}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
</ui:inputSelect>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the exact scenario. Please create a string attribute and assign the value of taskrec.status to that string attribute in your doinit and when picklist value is changed you can call on change to set taskrec.status or pass this string value to apex and set it there.

Please let me know if this helps